# Recommend hosted Ad Manager for displaying ads on web sites

Tags: ads, openx, ad-management

What would be a good hosted ad manager for displaying advertising on a site?

I've heard [OpenX](http://www.openx.org/), but never used it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

klausbyskov mentioned AdSense but it is not the same sort of thing at all. When you use it, you're basically handing over the selling of your ad space to the bidding mechanism at Google. That's not necessarily a bad thing, but it's not for every site. That's because you may be selling some of your own ad space if you're a larger site, then you need a tool that can mix multiple sources of ads together.

I've known several people who used OpenX but had complaints about it. Some have recommended [Google Ad Manager](https://www.google.com/admanager/login/en_US/index.html) as an alternative but I've not had a chance to try it yet.

It was requested that I add specific OpenX complaints. Here are a selection of quotes (from a website that may not be named):

1. OpenX is slow as "insert something offensive here".
2. It's fairly OK for a stock installation, "but if you're going to want to do much custom modifications with it, especially on the recent versions, just don't BLEEPING bother".
3. Not a fan of hooks.

This is just a selection of the complaints. However, all of the complaints were predicated on the idea that you were hosting it yourself. The version where they host it may be quite different.

Comment: Any specific complaints about OpenX. Thanks for the Google Ad Manager reference.

Answer (score 2):

We use a commercial enterprise level ad server called Ad Serving Solutions http://www.adservingsolutions.com/ which has beat our expectations. We are able to customize it and use cdn because of the scalable architecture. Has been a blessing compared to others on the market.

Answer (score 0):

What about [Google AdSense](https://www.google.com/adsense/) ?

Comment: AdSense is not exactly what I'm looking for. It displays Google's ads. I'm looking to display my client's ads.

Answer (score 0):

We are setting up such service: http://openadstore.com We are going to have free subscription with some moderate amount of monthly views. 
You can also ask us to help you with the installation of our open source software: http://www.adserverbeans.com You will only be paying for the hosting to your hosting provider.

I've seen a few commercial services that offer free initial subscription to their service. Check around.